# SSRS Tablix - Grouping and summing data by one or more fields WITHOUT showing details?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a dataset that I'm using for several Tablix, rather than create another dataset with the same sql + grouping by Dept, user - I was hoping to just use the same original detail dataset and do the grouping in SSRS.

I have data that looks like this:

```
NAME         DEPT        HOURS     MONTH 
Joe          Acct        2         1/1/2023
Joe          Acct        1         2/1/2023
Joe          Acct        10        3/1/2023
Tim          Acct        5         1/1/2023
Tim          Acct        6         2/1/2023
Tim          Acct        7         3/1/2023
Alex         IT          1         1/1/2023
Alex         IT          2         2/1/2023
Alex         IT          3         3/1/2023
```

And I want the output to look like this:

```
                       HOURS
ACCT                    26
Joe                     13
Tim                     13
IT                       6
Alex                     6
```

I can create a group, but there is still a "Details" row with the 3 lines - do I need to hide that?  Or is there a way to create a tablix where I can group/sum the data up by DEPT and NAME?

Help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: if you've created the row groups that you need, you can just delete the details row group.

Comment: If the future, you should add the NAME grouping to the detail group to change it to a NAME summary and then add the grouping for the DEPT rather than add the groups and delete the detail line.

Comment: thank you both, I ended up just adding the groupings and "hiding" the details row.  I didn't know if I could / should delete it so I left it for now.  Not sure if that will backfire on me.  I appreciate the advice and responses.